# Latex equation does not properly split in quarto

Tags: katex, quarto

#### Goal

To render a long latex equation in two lines in quarto

#### YAML

```
---
title: "ABC"
description: "XYZ"
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: full
    toc-location: left
    html-math-method: katex
---
```

#### Attempts

The attempts and renders are as follows:

**Attempt 1**

```
$$
v_n(t+\tau) = {min} \left\{v_n(t) + 2.5 a_n\tau (1-v_n(t)/V_n){(0.025+v_n(t)/V_n)}^{1/2}, \\ b_n\tau+\sqrt{b_n^2\tau^2 -b_n [ 2[x_{n-1}(t)-s_{n-1}-x_n(t)] - v_n(t)\tau- v_{n-1}(t)^2\hat{b}]}\right\}
$$
```

[image]

**Attempt 2**

```
$$
\begin{split}
v_n(t+\tau) = {min} \left \{v_n(t) + 2.5 a_n\tau(1-v_n(t)/V_n){(0.025+v_n(t)/V_n)}^{1/2}, \\ b_n \tau + \sqrt{b_n^2 \tau^2 - b_n [2 [x_{n-1}(t) - s_{n-1} - x_n(t)]] - v_n(t) \tau - v_{n-1}(t)^2 \hat{b}]} \right \}
\end{split} 
$$
```

[image]

**Attempt 3**: Remove `\left` and `\right`

[image]

But I want large braces. How can I fix this?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit on https://tex.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @pjs the question is about rendering `latex` in `quarto`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with quarto and the tag has no description, hence my question.

Comment: @pjs Quarto: https://quarto.org/

Comment: Even if Quarto is the rendering environment the problem is still finding the right LaTeX incantation, isn't it?

Comment: @pjs By incantation do you mean LaTeX distribution? I am using `katex`.

Comment: Incantation is an English word for a magical chant or phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line break will not work inside the `\left..\right` group. Instead, try `\biggl..\biggr`.

---

```
---
title: "ABC"
description: "XYZ"
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: full
    toc-location: left
    html-math-method: katex
---

## Quarto

### Long Math equation


$$
v_n(t+\tau) = {min} \biggl\{v_n(t) + 2.5 a_n\tau (1-v_n(t)/V_n){(0.025+v_n(t)/V_n)}^{1/2}, \\ b_n\tau+\sqrt{b_n^2\tau^2 -b_n [ 2[x_{n-1}(t)-s_{n-1}-x_n(t)] - v_n(t)\tau- v_{n-1}(t)^2\hat{b}]}\biggr\}
$$
```

The rendered document looks like this,

[image: long_math_equation]

---

**Also note that, you cannot use `eqnarray` here, because this environment is not supported in `katex`**. [see here](https://katex.org/docs/supported.html#environments) what environments are supported in `katex`

Comment: Thank you so much. I added a few `~` and that indented the second line correctly.

Comment: Note that while you can't use `eqnarray`, you can accomplish the same goal with `align`.

Comment: I have tested with `align` but it did not work as expected.

Comment: @umairdurrani `align` not working for you surprises me, since the updated solution based on it which I posted works like a champ on the sixthform.info site.

Answer (score 1):

Using `eqnarray*`, `\phantom`, and `\vphantom` to help with horizontal alignment and vertical sizing seemed to do the trick:

```latex
\begin{eqnarray*}
v_n(t+\tau) &=& \min\left\{v_n(t) + 2.5 a_n\tau (1-v_n(t)/V_n){(0.025+v_n(t)/V_n)}^{1/2}, \vphantom{\sqrt{b_n^2\hat{b}}} \right. \\
 & & \phantom{\min}\left. b_n\tau+\sqrt{b_n^2\tau^2 -b_n [ 2[x_{n-1}(t)-s_{n-1}-x_n(t)] - v_n(t)\tau- v_{n-1}(t)^2\hat{b}]}\right\}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Note that the `\left\{` needs to be balanced by a `\right.` on the first line, and similarly for the close bracket on the second line with `\left.` and `\right\}`. The `\vphantom{\sqrt...}` in the first line gives the left bracket the same height as the right bracket on the second line.

Also note that I switched `{min}` to `\min` to lose the math italicization.

Here's the result from my LaTeX environment:

[image: Formula split across two lines w/ large brackets]

---

### UPDATE

I tracked down the KaTeX online editor at https://katex.org and was able to confirm that while `eqnarray` doesn't work, the `phantom`, `vphantom`, and period versions of `\left`/`right` do work. Enter the following line in the `Type an expression:` box on the katex website to confirm the solution.

```latex
v_n(t+\tau) = {min} \left\{v_n(t) + 2.5 a_n\tau (1-v_n(t)/V_n){(0.025+v_n(t)/V_n)}^{1/2}, \vphantom{\sqrt{b_n^2\hat{b}}} \right. \\
\phantom{v_n(t+\tau) = }\left. b_n\tau+\sqrt{b_n^2\tau^2 -b_n [ 2[x_{n-1}(t)-s_{n-1}-x_n(t)] - v_n(t)\tau- v_{n-1}(t)^2\hat{b}]}\right\}
```

I also found on https://sixthform.info/katex/examples/demo.html that you can use a `\begin{align*}`/`\end{align*}` environment to achieve behavior similar to `eqnarray*`:

```latex
\begin{align*}
v_n(t+\tau) =& \min\left\{v_n(t) + 2.5 a_n\tau (1-v_n(t)/V_n){(0.025+v_n(t)/V_n)}^{1/2}, \vphantom{\sqrt{b_n^2\hat{b}}} \right. \\
  & \phantom{\min}\left. b_n\tau+\sqrt{b_n^2\tau^2 -b_n [ 2[x_{n-1}(t)-s_{n-1}-x_n(t)] - v_n(t)\tau- v_{n-1}(t)^2\hat{b}]}\right\}
\end{align*}
```

I personally prefer this solution since it allows indentation for readability on the second line, matches the sizes of the brackets to the size of the boxes being enclosed, and maximizes similarity to the pure LaTeX solution (in case portability might be a future concern).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, `quarto` does not even render the equation when I use your solution. I see the raw syntax back.

Comment: That's a good solution. But OP is using `katex` to render math equations in HTML and `katex` doesn't support `eqnarray` .

Comment: @umairdurrani See the update, now that I'm aware of KaTeX limitations.

Comment: @pjs Thank you for taking the time to find a solution. `align`, `\left.`, `\right.`, and `\vphantom` combination in your second solution accomplishes the goal.

Comment: @umairdurrani You’re welcome. I wasn’t aware of katex or quarto, so I found it interesting. Gotta keep learning now that I’m retired!